# How do I dispatch a mousedown/click event on the window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I want to dispatch a mouse event, just as if a user clicked a point on the screen. I do not know the target, I just have the coordinates. How do I dispatch it? I tried this, but it does not seem to work.

```js
const mouseEv = new MouseEvent("click", {
    screenX: X,
    screenY: Y,
});
window.dispatchEvent(mouseEv);
document.dispatchEvent(mouseEv);
document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(mouseEv);
```

Comment: Is the problem that you need to figure out which element that X and Y will be pointing at, so you can dispatch the event to that element?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Do you mean I should use `getElementFromPoint` (or what it is called)? Yes, I could do that but I would prefer to send the mouse event.

Comment: Yes, identify the element, and then send the mouse event to that element - that sounds like what you want?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, but it seems a bit unnecessary work. And I would like to use the coordinates the same way as if the user clicked. (It will be a new contenteditable element.) But maybe that works the way you suggests?

Comment: You have to identify the topmost element in the window at that point anyway, a single function call to figure that out isn't too tedious. Then just call `dispatchEvent` on that element (it'll capture/bubble for you, no need to specify every element between it and the top element)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok, thanks. I was not sure.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hm. It kind of works, but not as if the user clicked at that point. (Which was part of the trouble I wanted to avoid. But maybe that is not possible.)